# How to stop loading Worksheet_Change function before running a macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a macro to collate data from various sources in different sheets. I want to run the track changes code [here](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/highlite.htm) after collating the data. However, since this code is within Worksheet_Change function, it is loading even before running the macro which is attached to a button. So the moment I run the macro, it is marking all the data as changed. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Simply added a If Then conditional statement which would break out if certain conditions are not met and wait for the macro to check in.

Comment: The best solution is to use application.enableevents = false, as suggested by Jeeped.

Comment: like a module global/public variable set to true when you hit the button to start the macro? same way you would prevent changes in a userform (in userforms application.enableevents don't work, so back to what i said)

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when a `Worksheet_Change` event macro has a chance of changing data on the worksheet, you would include the line `Application.EnableEvents = False` so the event is not triggered and `Worksheet_Change` does not try to run on top of itself. If the macro is *'within Worksheet_Change function'* then this would be a wise addition.

If I have misunderstood and the macro is outside of the `Worksheet_Change` event macro, you can still include that line of code within the macro to halt changes to cell values on the worksheet triggering `Worksheet_Change` while the macro runs.

Remember to add `Application.EnableEvents = True` before exiting so that events are reenabled.